# Finding index of array in 2 multidimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an array

```
v = (x,y,z)
```

and two multidimensional array

```
l = (a,b,c),(d,e,f)
```

and

```
r = (g,h,i),(l,m,n),(x,y,z).
```

I want to know the index of `v` no matter if is in the first or second multidimensional array. I tried `numpy.where(v==l)[0][0]` but it returns:

> Index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0.

Works only if I know before the matrix where I have to search the Index, but I don't. Thanks

And If I want to know the index and the array that contains it?

Comment: What is your actual data like? Are you talking about tuples, Python lists or NumPy arrays?

Comment: What do you want as output here? By returning just index how would you know in which array you found it?

Comment: I'm talking of np.arrays that could be huges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function that accepts the item to be searched and the list of array to be searched in and use a loop to find that item in each array. Use exception handling to catch the `IndexError`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> v = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> r = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [0, 9, 8], [2, 4, 4]])
>>> l = np.array([[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
def get_index(seq, *arrays):
    for array in arrays:
        try:
            return np.where(array==seq)[0][0]
        except IndexError:
            pass
...         
>>> get_index(v, r, l)
0
>>> get_index(np.array([7, 8, 9]), r, l)
1
```

You'd get `None` as output if the item is not found in any of the array.

**Update:**

If you want the name as well then pass the arrays in a dictionary:

```
 def get_index(seq, **arrays):
    for name, array in arrays.items():
        try:
            return name, np.where(array==seq)[0][0]
        except IndexError:
            pass
...         
>>> get_index(v, **dict(r=r, l=l))
('r', 0)
>>> get_index(np.array([7, 8, 9]), **dict(r=r, l=l))
('l', 1)
```

Comment: Ashwini if I want to know also in wich matrix is r or l?

Comment: @user3154159 Their names or just their value?

Comment: The name r or l and index of v in r or l

Comment: @user3154159 AFAIK numpy arrays don't have any `__name__` attribute, so you'll have to pass in a dict. Check out the updated solution.

Comment: It Works very well. You're amazing. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
def containsArray(v):
    for index, arr in enumerate(l):
        if v == arr:
            ret index;

    for index, arr in enumerate(r):
        if v == arr:
            ret index;
```

Comment: It works, but it's not Pythonic to iterate over list with index. Please, don't write C in Python - it's ugly!

Comment: I don't know if the v array is in l or r

Comment: I need the index of v in r or l

Comment: @user3154159 then separate the for loops into 2 different functions and call them appropriately